# nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 1 Connection has no connected handler

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, device, mqtt

I'm working on sending and receiving messages via MQTT, I'm using mqttClient framework: 
https://github.com/ckrey/MQTT-Client-Framework

Specifically this class: https://github.com/ckrey/MQTT-Client-Framework/blob/master/MQTTSwift/MQTTSwift/MQTTSwift.swift

So this is all working just fine using Xcode simulator, publish and subscribe and so receiving the data (messages) just as it should **BUT** once I connect my iPhone I could not see my data on the debug screen as it used to be and all I can get is this

> **nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 1 Connection has no connected handler.**

I was trying to solve this all day but no use,

Answer (score 0):

You have to give proper IPAddress instead of "localhost" if used.

It solved my issue.